# cant add or update a foreign key in hibernate and spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

guys i have 2 tables "employee" which has EMPID, EMPAGE, ADDRESS, SALARY, EMPNAME, department_id (foreign key refrences to table "department") and "department" table which has department_id, name ... here is my Department.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="department",cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },  fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Employee> employees;
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}
```

and Employee.java

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
private Department department;
public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}
```

and in my service

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false)
public void addEmployee(String[] list, Employee employee) {
    employee.getDepartment().setDepId(Integer.parseInt(list[3])); // exception in this line
    employee.setEmpName(list[2]);
    employee.setEmpAge(Integer.parseInt(list[4]));
    employee.setEmpAddress(list[6]);
    employee.setSalary(list[1]);
    this.employeeDao.addOrEditEmployee(employee);
}
```

here is my error

```html
Apr 10, 2016 1:27:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [sdnext] in context with path [/Spring3HibernateApp1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:27)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.addEmployee(Unknown Source)
 at com.dineshonjava.controller.EmployeeController.doPostSave(EmployeeController.java:65)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: post yuor error stacktrace

Comment: done .. plz have a look

Comment: post when you use the method addEmployee(

Comment: i am adding it right .. and the proof is when deleting the line that gives me exception everything is goes fine

Comment: i mean when yu call the method because maybe list is null

Comment: when clicking on add button

Comment: where is this clicking button

Comment: it is not null i debugged it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `employee.getDepartment()` is the issue of error because the instance `employee` still null you can't `getDepartment` you need to setDepartment:

```
  public void addEmployee(String[] list,Employee employee) {
    employee.setDepartment(..); 
    ...
  }
```

Comment: same exception .. any other suggestions ??